# How to remove one class and add another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have 4 buttons:

When you hover over them, they toggle color to #DCDCDC.

When you click on the button with ID #correct then that button turns to #5FEB6D.
(or so it should)

I can get the mouseenter/mosueout toggle class to work, however, I can't get the if statement to check if this button with class .q1 and ID = #correct then remove the hover class and add 'theright' class to change the color to #5FEB6D.

**JQUERY CODE**

```
if ($(this).is(".q1")) {
  if ($(this).is("#correct")) {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("hoverover");
          $(this).addClass("theright");
    })
  }
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<style>
  .hoverover{
    background: #DCDCDC;
  }
  .theright{
    background: #5FEB6D;
  }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="q1" id=correct type="button">Fatigue Approval Sheet</button></td>
      <td><button class="q1" type="button">Fatigue Analysis Sheet</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><button class=q1 type="button">Fatigue Analysis Spreadsheet</button></td>
      <td><button class=q1 type="button">Fatigue Approval Spreadsheet</button></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Check the documentation an re-read what [`.click(function() { ... })`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) does

Comment: Aha! I see, I should have used the .click event before the if statement. It has worked now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside button click you can check your condition.

No need to check double `if` condition. You can check condition on  single `if` statement  using and (&&) operator.

If your condition match add / remove class.

You can add and remove class on single chaining method `$(this).removeClass("hoverover").addClass("theright");`

```js
$('table tr td button').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(".q1") && $(this).is("#correct"))
    $(this).removeClass("hoverover").addClass("theright");
  else {
    // Do whatever you want or do nothing
  }
});
```

```css
.hoverover {
  background: #DCDCDC;
}

.theright {
  background: #5FEB6D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q1" id=correct type="button">Fatigue Approval Sheet</button></td>
    <td><button class="q1" type="button">Fatigue Analysis Sheet</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q1 type="button">Fatigue Analysis Spreadsheet</button></td>
    <td><button class=q1 type="button">Fatigue Approval Spreadsheet</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```